# Java class path completely ignored (OS X)

Tags: mac-osx, java, classpath

I'm trying to run a jar that is located at /Library/Java/jack.jar, this works:

```
java -jar /Library/Java/jack.jar
```

However, I want to run it without the path, relying on the class path. The default class path includes /Library/Java, but this fails with "Unable to access jarfile":

```
java -jar jack.jar
```

Why? What's more, this also fails (same error):

```
java -cp /Library/Java -jar jack.jar
```

What's the problem/what am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jar file can not be executed this way. You need to provide the full path of the jar file. the class path `-cp classpath` specifies a list of directories, JAR archives, and ZIP archives to search for class files needed to run your java program. However, the jar file to be executed should be accessed using full path. After the jar file is run, the classpath can be used to locate more classes and libraries.

By the way, this is not the right site to ask such a question.

Comment: Ahhhh OK. So there's no way Java can be configured to search a default environment defined directory for JARs to execute using the "java -jar ..." command? The jarfile argument always has to be explicit?

Comment: RE the right site: Sorry, I wasn't sure, thought this counted as server configuration.

Comment: @JackSleight: AFAIK, yes the jar file path should be set explicitly.

Comment: Yes, this problem got me once also, trying to run java from a powershell script:  http://thegreenoak.blogspot.com/2009/07/run-java-process-from-windows.html

Answer (score 3):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html:

```
-jar
When you use this option, the JAR file is the source 
of all user classes, and other user class path settings
are ignored.
```